# How do I achieve sharp and brightly coloured pictures on a Canon EOS700D/T5I?

Tags: photo-editing, sharpness, canon-700d

I see some pictures posted and they are glossy, sharp and solid. I always  wonder how they achieved it. I have a 18-55mm lens for now. Is it possible to get this result on that lens or do I really need to upgrade?

Comment: Post one or more of those pictures that you see and one of yours. Your question is very broad. Posting images for comparison will attract better answers.

Answer (score 0):

To get sharper images

- Use an appropriate shutter speed, that prevents camera shake and/or
  subject movement from blurring the image.
- Use a flash to freeze any motion of the subject.
- close the aperture, (that means: use a bigger number, something like
  f8 will do) the effect is minor, it will not turn a blurry shot into an
  "oh my gosh this is amazingly sharp"-image

To get bright colors

- Do not shoot into the sun. It causes colors to look washed out.
- Photograph something that actually is bright and colorful.

---

But most importantly:

Apply proper post processing. Whatever sharp and colorful picture you stumbled upon on the web is probably heavily post processed. You will **not** get such a result straight out of the camera.

Your equipment is fine.
It's time to upgrade your skills and knowledge how to use it.

Comment: I thought sharpness was also a factor of aperture...then again it is a triangle.

Comment: @SailorCire that's true, but to a smaller extend. I will add it.